# Why Spring AOP is not working for method call inside another method?

Tags: java, spring-aop

Why Spring AOP is not working for method call inside another method?

```
public class TestAOPService {
    public String getSum(int val1) {
        System.out.println(val1);

        calculateSum(val1, 12);
    }

    public void calculateSum(int val1, int val2){

        System.out.println("Sum" + (val1 + val2));
    }

}
```

can anyone explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

[Because of how proxying works.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)

For example, Spring creates a bean, an instance of type `TestAOPService`. Then it realizes it needs to proxy it to add aspect advice. It will take the class (and interface) type of the instance and create either a JDK proxy or a CGLIB proxy.

The proxy will wrap the actual instance and delegate to it after/around/before executing the advice.

It looks like this

```
Caller --> Proxy.getSum(..) --> Bean.getSum(..)
```

So the caller is invoking the method on the proxy and the proxy contains the advice behavior. But, if you call a method of the instance within a method of the instance, it looks like so

```
Caller --> Proxy.getSum(..) --> Bean.getSum(..) --> Bean.calculateSum(..)
```

In code, you'd have this

```
public String getSum(int val1) {
    System.out.println(val1);

    calculateSum(val1, 12);
}
```

which is actually

```
public String getSum(int val1) {
    System.out.println(val1);

    this.calculateSum(val1, 12);
}
```

The method is invoked directly on the instance, not on the proxy. Therefore no advice can be applied.