# Intercept whole class with Java standard features

Tags: java, api, websphere, interceptor, intercept

I want to intercept a whole class with java standard features, because i am not allowed to add new dependencies to the project (websphere 85).

I want to call a function, which does multiple api calls (swagger generated) for example myapi.bla(), myapi.blabla(), etc and get the headers from the response.
I thought about intercepting all methods of the class "myapi" and then access the headers (myapi.getApiClient.getResponseheaders).

Do you know how to intercept all methods of a class with java or websphere85 built in features?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are prominently 2 ways to achieve this,

1. [AOP](https://docs.jboss.org/aop/1.0/aspect-framework/userguide/en/html/what.html), you can use [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to achieve this which basically modifies the class to inject interceptions, either at compile or load time. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172729).
2. [Dynamic Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html). [A good explanation on how to use it with example.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies) [Though it comes with a performance cost.](http://ordinaryjava.blogspot.com/2008/08/benchmarking-cost-of-dynamic-proxies.html)